# I am sick and tired of hearing this

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> A US state
>
> declares victory
>
> showing an important document
>
> in the last year of a wonderful 7 year period

What is that?

Comment: Is your name a clue too? :)

Comment: Haha. Indeed. But just sick and tired of constantly hearing that word all day. But it is serious.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since no subject is taboo for us word players, I'm just gonna go with

> **COVID-19**

A US state

> **CO** is the abbreviation for Colorado

declares victory

> The **V** sign with 2 fingers

showing an important document

> **ID** is an important document you show

in the last year of a wonderful 7 year period

> **19** is the last year of the wonderful 7 year period known as "teens".

Topic: I am sick and tired of hearing this

> Just in case you've missed it, there's a spot of this pandemic thing going on around the world. Might want to avoid it.

Comment: D'oh, you just pipped me to it! And I think your reasoning for the '7 year period' is sound - that was the part I struggled with. Well done :)

Answer (score 18):

I think you are sick and tired of hearing about:

> **COVID-19** (which seems to be in the news *a lot* right now...)

*A US state*

> **CO** is the abbreviation for Colorado.

*declares victory*

> **V** is for Victory, and indicated by the [V sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_sign) hand gesture.

*showing an important document*

> Your **ID** (e.g. passport, driver's licence) is an important document for proving your identity.

*in the last year of a wonderful 7 year period*

> I presumed (incorrectly - see @Bass' answer for what is surely the correct logic) that there was some significance to the year 20**19** marking the end of a great 7-year period - possibly in the US - which I couldn't quite place. For me personally, the 7 years 2013-19 marked the first 7 years that my beloved [AFC Bournemouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.F.C._Bournemouth) enjoyed success in the top two divisions of English football *ever* - for the first time in their entire history - before their unfortunate relegation in 2020...! (Though I am sure this is not your reasoning ;-))

You might also be feeling *sick and tired* of this...

> if you are showing any of its symptoms! Get well soon :)

Comment: Ha! Got you by almost an entire minute! :-)

Comment: I am amazed to see that two correct answers, once again, were posted within ONE minute of each other and that too after 3 hours of puzzle posting time. Wow. Kudos @Bass and Stiv

Comment: For our family, coronavirus is manageable... the AFCB relegation is not :-( :-p :-)

Answer (score 9):

Answer could be

> **CAREFULLY**

A US state

> **CA** - California

declares victory

> **REF** - Referee

showing an important document

> **ULL** -Unsigned Long Long - Longest data type for integers - storing and printing images (Stretch)

in the last year of a wonderful 7 year period

> **Y** - Last letter in Seven years of PLENT**Y**

Title

> Constantly being told to do things **CAREFULLY** can be stressful. It has become especially prevalent in the current situation with COVID-19.

Comment: -1 for "important document == ULL - a data type". No reason given for the data type to be associated with image storage, and no reason given for image storage to be associated with important documents.

Comment: @Brondahl, I agree. It was a stretch. My thought process was a little off - and long winded. I think some of these upvotes are for the fact that I wrote the actual answer in my explanation and 9 minutes later, the correct answer was found. So, my answer appeared helpful. If not, it was a huge coincidence. I could be wrong though. I'm wrong a lot. lol.

Comment: @MacGyver88 It absolutely *was* your use of that word within your explanation that suddenly sparked something for me. While reading it I suddenly went "That must be it!" immediately followed by "Oh no! You were so close to it and never realised!" Providing a flash of inspiration - even if unintended! - is definitely worth something :)

Comment: @Stiv, I thought so. I'm usually pretty adept at reading the room. The slowness of the queue made me think it was a possibility. I love it!

Comment: FWIW the term is unsigned (i.e. never negative) not un*as*signed (i.e. having no current value)

Comment: @Timbo, Oops. I must have overlooked that. Thanks. :)