# A Rich Club Indeed

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This puzzle is linked to

[I am sick and tired of hearing this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101751/i-am-sick-and-tired-of-hearing-this)

> A Person
>
> From a City in Europe
>
> Visits a Country Club
>
> to offer Computer Related
>
> Teaching

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's

> the football/soccer club 'Manchester United'

A Person

> Man

From a City in Europe

> [Chester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chester)

Visits a Country Club

> UN (United Nations)

to offer Computer Related

> IT (Information Technology)

Teaching

> ED (Education)